# Problems with qSort

Tags: c++, qt, qsort

I got a little problem with qSort.
I just want to sort my list after adding a vertex to my QList m_acceptedVertices.

```
bool Vertex::greaterThan(Vertex * v1, Vertex *v2){

    return this->computeDistanceTo(v1) > this->computeDistanceTo(v2);
}

void Vertex::acceptVertex(Vertex* vert)
{

    m_acceptedVertices.append(vert);

    qSort(m_acceptedVertices.begin(), m_acceptedVertices.end(), greaterThan);

}
```

But I still getting these Errors:

> Fehler: C3867: 'Vertex::greaterThan': function call missing argument
> list; use '&Vertex::greaterThan' to create a pointer to member
>
> Fehler: C2780: 'void qSort(Container &)' : expects 1 arguments - 3 provided
>
> Fehler: C2780: 'void qSort(RandomAccessIterator,RandomAccessIterator)' : expects 2 > arguments - 3 provided

What am I doing wrong?
Can sombody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try what the compiler suggests ... ?

Comment: Why don't you use [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) from the C++ standard library? It might be slightly more efficient (because template instantiation could be inlined) and it is certainly more readable (more type-checked) and shorter...

Comment: qsort or qSort? These things matter!

Comment: `greaterThan` has to return `int`, not `bool` (at least for `qsort` -- I don't know about `qSort`).

Comment: You can't use a member function for qSort. Make it a free function/global function or declare it static. Other options include a functor object or with C++11 use a lambda.

Comment: i get these errors with qSort. i read the Qt documentation and did it like the example. but i still get these errors

Comment: BTW, `computeDistanceTo` is probably a bit expensive and sorting whole collection after each insert might be not the best idea. Have you considered `std::set`?

Comment: I presume you mean the [QT qSort](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qSort-2); you should probably say so explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You have a design issue, your comparator is supposed to be a free function (or a functor) comparing 2 `Vertex`, your implementation should probably look something like :

```
bool greaterThan(Vertex * v1, Vertex *v2){

    return v1.computeDistanceTo(v2) > 0;
}
```

**2)** Use the standard library : [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) (it is most likely to perform a quicksort internally in most cases, but if you really want to use [`qSort`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html#qSort-3), it will work as well)

---

**[Minimal working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/398c2ecbfb416854)** with a free function comparator :

```
class Vertex {
    public:
     int i;
};

bool greaterThan(Vertex * v1, Vertex *v2)
{
    return v1->i > v2->i;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Vertex*> v;
    v.push_back(new Vertex { 5 });
    v.push_back(new Vertex { 1 });
    v.push_back(new Vertex { 3 });
    v.push_back(new Vertex { 6 });
    v.push_back(new Vertex { 2 });

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), &greaterThan);

    for(auto& ve : v)
       std::cout << ve->i << " ";
}
```

---

**Note:**

For simple comparison functions, lambdas are a good alternative:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [] (Vertex * v1, Vertex *v2) {return v1->i > v2->i;} );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++11 then probably you need something like that:

```
void Vertex::acceptVertex(Vertex* vert)
{
    m_acceptedVertices.append(vert);

    qSort(hallo.begin(), hallo.end(), 
          [this](Vertex* v1, Vertex* v2) {
               return this->computeDistanceTo(v1) > this->computeDistanceTo(v2);
          });
}
```

If you use older C++ you have to define functor object which will store pointer reference Vertex, or use lambda expression from boost.